# SAP Fiori - Facing error "Different strict handling requested within one changeset" in new RAP Fiori Application

Tags: error-handling, crud, sap-fiori, sap-gateway, rap

Hello stackoverflow community,

During the development of a Fiori app (we use RAP and the OData V2 model), we have an ObjectPage with an input field as a multi-input.

The user should later be able to enter (or delete) email addresses in this field. These addresses are linked to the root entity as a composition child.

To enable further functions elsewhere, a service was generated within the transaction SEGW.

Currently we are faced with the following challenge:

If one deletes an email address and edits another field on the ObjectPage, for example one changes a date field, an error message occurs when saving.

This reads: "Different strict handling requested within one changeset" (message SADL_GW, number 033). When analysing the error in the Chrome DevTools, we could see that almost all commands of our service have a line with the property "Prefer: handling=strict" in the '$batch'.

Only DELETE does not have this property. We assume that this is the reason for this error.

What we don't know yet is how it is possible to specify the same handling in all commands (CRUD operations?).

Do you have any advice for us?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.